# Cant Find Control Windows Phone 8.1 UAP

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am trying to find a control under my xaml in the hub control of windows phone 8.1. It may be the case my method works fine on desktop as I have testest it in wpf before but I am porting it to windows phone and may not work the same.

```
<Grid>
    <Hub Header="Lists" Name="mainHub" >
        <HubSection MinWidth="600" Name="lattestLists" Header="New Lists">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <ListBox Background="Transparent" Margin="6" Height="auto" BorderThickness="2" MaxHeight="580" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="listBoxobj"  >
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Width="350" >
                                    <Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="NameTxt" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="28" Foreground="White"/>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text=">" FontSize="28"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
                                            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PhoneTxt"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}" />
                                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,35,0" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="CreateddateTxt" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CreationDate}" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>

        <HubSection Header="Tech" IsHeaderInteractive="True" 
            Background="#222222" MinWidth="250">
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Tech news goes here."
                       Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Click the header to go to the Tech page."
                       Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>

        <HubSection Header="Sports" IsHeaderInteractive="True"
            Background="#444444" MinWidth="250">
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Sports news goes here."
                       Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Click the header to go to the Sports page."
                       Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>

</Grid>
```

I am trying to use the following method to find the lsitbox but its not working

```
      ListBox listBoxobjc = FindChildControl<ListBox>(this, "listBoxobj") as ListBox;
        listBoxobjc.ItemsSource = DB_ContactList.OrderByDescending(i => i.id).ToList();//Binding DB data to LISTBOX and Latest contact ID can Display first.
```

This is the method FindChildControl

```
  private DependencyObject FindChildControl<T>(DependencyObject control, string ctrlName)
    {
        int childNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);
        for (int i = 0; i < childNumber; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, i);
            FrameworkElement fe = child as FrameworkElement;
            // Not a framework element or is null
            if (fe == null) return null;

            if (child is T && fe.Name == ctrlName)
            {
                // Found the control so return
                return child;
            }
            else
            {
                // Not found it - search children
                DependencyObject nextLevel = FindChildControl<T>(child, ctrlName);
                if (nextLevel != null)
                    return nextLevel;
            }
        }
        return null;
  }
```

Edit
I debuged the code and its showing the control as null even though I have done the same way as i would

Comment: Have you debugged your code to see what's happening and why it doesn't work?

Comment: @Romasz yes its showing the object being null ie still cant find it within the hub control

Answer (score 0):

I have replace my method to find children a couple of times during the different versions of Windows Phone / Windows Runtime with this one being the most reliable. Just in case you're not able to spot the mistake you could also try this one and see if it yields better results:

```
public T FindElementByName<T>(DependencyObject element, string sChildName) where T : FrameworkElement
    {
        T childElement = null;
        var nChildCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);
        for (int i = 0; i < nChildCount; i++)
        {
            FrameworkElement child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as FrameworkElement;

            if (child == null)
                continue;

            if (child is T && child.Name.Equals(sChildName))
            {
                childElement = (T)child;
                break;
            }

            childElement = FindElementByName<T>(child, sChildName);

            if (childElement != null)
                break;
        }
        return childElement;
    }
```

Also when using this method shortly after creating / loading content I call UpdateLayout beforehand:

```
this.UpdateLayout();
```

But be careful - this is not one of the performance-friendliest methods (see also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.updatelayout).

Comment: thanks for this how do i call it for instance to find a listbox within hub section

Comment: I tried with the following but still states cant find the control


              ListBox listBoxobjc = FindElementByName<ListBox>(this, "listBoxobj") as ListBox;
            listBoxobjc.ItemsSource = DB_ContactList;